# ASP code to execute Stored Proc

Tags: stored-procedures, asp-classic

I am getting error trying to run my asp code for executing stored proc.

my code is:

```
Set conn = server.createobject("ADODB.connection")
conn.open

Set rs = server.createobject("ADODB.recordset")
strSQL = "exec spActiveEmployee"
rs.open strSQL, conn, 3, 3
```

I am getting an error that says:
- "Either BOF or EOF is True or the current record has been deleted"

Anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out: [Why do I get 'BOF or EOF' errors?](http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/why-do-i-get-bof-or-eof-errors.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a connection string.

```
conn.ConnectionString = "MyDatabase"
```